# How to stablish on delete action but skiping on severed (set to null)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Here are the classes example

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

here is the Fluent configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
            .WithOne(x => x.Child)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

and here is the operation.

```
var p = await _context.Parents
          .Where(x => x.ParentId == id)
          .Include(x => x.Child)
          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var p2 = await _context.Parents
          .Where(x => x.ParentId == id2)
          .Include(x => x.Child)
          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

//Below works just fine, remove the parent and child
_context.Parents.Remove(p);

//In this two is where I want to conserve the child in DB.
p2.Child = null;
//Or
p2.Child = new ();

_context.Update(p2);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

What I'm looking for is: to delete the dependent side when I delete the Principal, Done. If I set null the Child in the Parent, preserve the Child.

Any clue on this is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that does the deletion?   EF Core will manually try to delete dependent relationships, rather than using cascade deletes, but it does depend on how you call it.  Also, are you using EF core or EF framework?

Comment: Im using EF core, I will edit the question so you can see what im trying.

Comment: You say what you're looking for, not what problem you face. Anyway, it seems to work with EF-core 5.